# CVXPY exponent atom using Mosek

Tags: exponent, cvxpy, mosek

below is a snippet of code from my program.

```
import CVXPY as cp

X = cp.Variable(shape=(10,4), boolean = True)

y = cp.exp(X[0,1])

objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(X))

constraint = [y <= 0]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

result = prob.solve(solver = cp.MOSEK)
```

My question is that Mosek says that the number of exponential cones in my model is 40 instead of 1. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Using CVXPY 1.0.25 and Mosek 9.1.10 I see only one cone, as expected:

```
Problem
  Name                   :                 
  Objective sense        : min             
  Type                   : CONIC (conic optimization problem)
  Constraints            : 4               
  Cones                  : 1               
  Scalar variables       : 44              
  Matrix variables       : 0               
  Integer variables      : 40
```

(after fixing small typos in your code).